# Body style is no longer applied

Tags: css

I had the following CSS.

```
body {
        font-family: Arial;    
        font-size: 12px;       
        color: #666666;        
        line-height: 18px;     
        background: url('../bg.jpg') no-repeat bottom left;
}
```

Rules for body strangely stopped to be applied. When I change the parameters nothing happens.
I solved it as follows.

```
body {
            font-family: Arial;    
            font-size: 12px;       
            color: #666666;        
            line-height: 18px;     
            background: url('../bg.jpg') no-repeat bottom left;
    }
body {
            font-family: Arial;    
            font-size: 12px;       
            color: #666666;        
            line-height: 18px;     
            background: url('../bg.jpg') no-repeat bottom left;
    }
```

and it's working, but when I delete one body { ... } rules it isn't working.

Do you know why this happens?

thank you

Comment: Which browser is this with? Is there other stuff in the CSS file that could be interfering with it?

Comment: In chromium and firefox. Which stuff do you mean? I have to paste the same body {} style twice. It was working with one before.

Comment: By stuff I mean anything else in the CSS file apart from that body rule.

Comment: Probably yes. Because if I delete everything except body {} it works. But what could interfere with it? I wasn't able to change more parameters in the body.

Comment: Can you put the rest of the css file in this question, or give us a link to it so I can see?

Comment: what's the rule before `body` in the stylesheet.. is it's punctuation, curly braces , colons and semi-colons valid.. have you pasted the stylesheet into the [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input)? - that's the quickest way to find a parse error

Comment: Thank you both, there was a lexical error (deleted / from /* comment style)

Comment: maybe a cache problem, Did you try ctr+f5 ( or delete all browser's cache? )

Comment: @eveevans It was lexical error. CSS validator suggested by clairesuzy helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that there are no statements above with syntactical errors such as unclosed braces ({})or unterminated rules (;). Running this through the CSS validator might flag these issues for you: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/